# Scrapy xpath major issues...

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I really have no idea how to use xpath in scrapy... I thought I did but apparently I am lost.

Here is the page I am scraping:

```
http://chc.tbe.taleo.net/chc01/ats/careers/requisition.jsp?org=INTELLIGENESIS&cws=1&rid=413
```

Here is my XPATH for the job title:

```
  item['title'] = job.xpath('//*[@id="siteWrapper"]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/h1/text()').extract()
```

So... whats up with scrapy not scraping anything....

I have tried MANY different ways of writing the xpath to no avail....

Comment: Have you tried without the `tbody`?

Comment: Why did that work? I have to know lol.. beating my head against this crap for an hour... the xpath works everywhere else ive tried except scrapy...

Comment: Sure, `tbody` is generated by the browser - please see the question I've linked as a duplicate.

Comment: Sorry for creating a duplicate... i searched for a while but wasn't looking for the right keywords.